# Primary key is not deleted when I deleted table inside SSMS- SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I have a table and I need to insert a huge number of records, so I create my table without primary key to make the insert faster. when I finished insert, I create primary key for that table using this command:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY (MyTableId)
```

The problem is if I delete the table inside SQL Server management studio then the next time when I want to create this primary key, it says :

```
 The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because
 a duplicate key was found for the object name
```

I need to let SQL knows that this primary key is connected to that table and must automatically be deleted when the table is being deleted.

Comment: Are you deleting the data in the table or dropping the table

Comment: No I go to SSMS right click on the table and then deleted it

Comment: is your alter primary key created when run the script on first time?

Comment: have you tried dropping the constraint, e.g.  `ALTER TABLE MyTable DROP CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable`

Comment: @StephanLechner I know we can solve it by this script. My question was how we can ignore it. As the table might be deleted from SSMS or anywhere else.

Comment: is your table data inserted without primary key on the first time.. i think this is not a primary key problem.. it's data problem i guess.. your are not allowed to create a primary key because you have a duplicate value for your primary key column.. i guess...

Comment: Did you try to check your data value if there's a duplicate on your primary key column?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing but you're misdiagnosing the issue. When you drop a table, all indexes and constraints on that table *are* removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is not a primary key problem. It is a problem with your data. You are not allowed to create a primary key because you have a duplicate value in your primary key column.

You could run a query to confirm that you have a duplicate.

```
SELECT
    MyTableId,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    MyTable
GROUP BY
    MyTableId
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: I think you missunderstood the question. From what I understand, the problem is that the primary key constraint is not dropped when the table is dropped.

Comment: The primary key is always associated with a table. So if you drop a table, the primary key will also be dropped. Not only the primary key, all the indexes and constraints on that table are dropped too.

Comment: He may be misdiagnosing the issue. Since he is trying to create the primary key after inserting the data, there is a good chance to have a duplicate.

Comment: *"a duplicate key was found for the object name"* - That's not data.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - run `create table T(ID int not null); insert into T(ID) values (1),(1); alter table T add constraint UQ_ID UNIQUE (ID)` in an empty database. This *is* the error message you receive and it *is* data related.

Answer (score 0):

The Best Answer to dropping the table containing Primary and foreign constraints is :

Step 1 : Drop the Primary key of the table.
Step 2 : Now it will prompt whether to delete all the foreign references or not.
Step 3 : Delete the table.